# Answering a question which is then edited.

Tags: discussion

Some context:

A user posted a question asking about clarification of notation in a problem statement. I answered the question and then left my computer for a bit. I came back 20 minutes later and found that the user had changed his question and that my answer was flagged for review as a "low quality post", with one user commenting "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post."

I deleted my answer, but if I had not come back to my computer, I probably would've had a ton of down-votes.

What is the best course of action here?

EDIT: The other question is pretty close to mine, but I am also curious about how to respond to the negative feedback which results, e.g. comments and down-votes (which I don't think the other question addresses)

Comment: The best course of action is not to edit a question so that it fundamentally changes the question after it has an answer. You didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: To give a meaningful answer it'd help to see the particular instance. Please link to it. On how to respond, well, just say what you said here, i.e, that your post was based on an earlier version. Or just respond nothing and delete. (Or, try to get a roll back of the question via an edit. But I would only do that if you invested non-minimal effort into your answer.)